# How to resize picture so that its height matches adjacent text

Tags: html, css

I would like to create two adjacent `<div>`'s satisfying the following properties:

- The left one contains a picture, and the right one contains some text.
- The picture is resized so that its height matches the height of the text, without being distorted.
- The right `<div>` has its width extended fully to the edge of the screen.

Here is an example of what I mean. I have manually set the height of the image to `70px`, but I would like this to be automatically set so that the two blocks have the same height.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.right {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/stack-of-colorful-books-left-border-picture-id147704087" style="height: 70px;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="right"> line 1 <br> line 2 <br> line 3 <br> line 4 </div>
</div>
```

I have heard that tables should not be used for this sort of thing, but if there is a solution with tables, I am okay with that.

Comment: Add `height: 100%;` to .left and add some css for the image `.left img { height: 100%; width: auto; border: 0; }` Maybe you have to add `display: inline-block;` to the img.

Comment: @bron That doesn't seem to be working for me. Here's a fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5adh4c9q/)

Comment: Does something like this help? http://jsfiddle.net/ez59g4a3/

Comment: @EGC Almost - I would like the picture to shrink down too, not just scale up

Comment: Yeah, that's no problem. The code I supplied will determine the height of the `.right` class and scale the image up or down depending on it's size.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. This is working for me now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed using tables for img and text presentation is not considered a good practice.
I should add that styling them inline also is not considered a good practice too.
In case you need to dynamically change those values in a web page tou could use javascripts native methods to get and set those heights.

```
var left = document.getElementsByClassName("left");
var height = left.clientHeight;
document.getElementsByClassName("right").style.height = left;
```

I should also note that you should keep in mind that you should calculate any other DOM space that the element might use, like padding margin or border.

Comment: When calculating with JS, use the onresize event to be responsive.